Siunitx package - NiceTabular environment - Preserve header from formatting
Simple issue that I cannot figure out.
I use a lot of table in my report and like the NiceTabular environment.
I also use Siunitx package in that environment to format numbers from my raw data. Very usefull.
My problem concerns the header row.
When I combine text and math in a header column (like "T<5°C" ), result is awful because siunitx tries to format it.
So I want to preserve this first row (header) from formatting by siunitx.
I looked for NiceMatrix and siunitx options, but cannot find anything to accomplish that.
\sisetup{
    detect-mode=,
    output-decimal-marker = {.},
    tight-spacing           = true,
    group-digits            = false,
    input-signs             = ,
    round-mode              = places,
    round-precision         = 2,
    minimum-decimal-digits=2,
    }
\centering  
\begin{NiceTabular}{rSSSSSSSSSSSSS}[]
\RowStyle[bold]{}
     Mois & $\overline{T^{\circ}C}$ & $\Delta T$ & $T < 5^{\circ}C$ & $5 \leq T^{\circ}C \leg 15$ & $T > 15$ \\
\midrule
     février & 8.47254464283035 & 1.4195684523541585 & 1.3283950620246907 & 1.569725557512863 & 1.1499999999999997 \\ 
     mars & 8.918010752688165 & 0.7305275763759163 & 1.1084677419354834 & 0.9387096774193541 & 1.2782258064516134 & 1.144318181818182 & 1.0973591549295765 & 1.1823076923076916 & 0.7075471698113205 & 1.0629629629629622 & 1.1655913978494623 & 1.1280528052805279 & 0.7266666666666666 \\
     avril & 10.958888888888891 & 1.0731944444444466 & 1.062962962962963 & 1.3280961182994457 & 1.0864000000000005 \\ 
     mai & 13.655555555555546 & 0.7385416666666575 & ~ & 0.9904522613065327 & 0.9280898876404503 \\
\midrule
\RowStyle[bold]{\itshape}
    Moyenne  &  9.96& 1.02 &1.2&1.3&0.97 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}


Thanks for your help.

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you post the code you have?

Try {...} around each cell

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, you’re a genius !

@Atiroocky You're welcome! It was a lucky guess as I couldn't test the code in your question due to missing packages.

I spent hours trying to figure it out, and problem solved in 10mn thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.
I had to add {…} for each cells that were bad formatted.
\sisetup{
detect-mode=,
output-decimal-marker = {.},
tight-spacing           = true,
group-digits            = false,
input-signs             = ,
round-mode              = places,
round-precision         = 2,
minimum-decimal-digits=2,
}
\centering  
\begin{NiceTabular}{rSSSSSSSSSSSSS}[]
\RowStyle[bold]{}
 Mois & $\overline{T^{\circ}C}$ & $\Delta T$ & {$T < 5^{\circ}C$} & {$5 \leq T^{\circ}C \leq 15$} & {$T > 15$} \\
\midrule
 février & 8.47254464283035 & 1.4195684523541585 & 1.3283950620246907 & 1.569725557512863 & 1.1499999999999997 \\ 
 mars & 8.918010752688165 & 0.7305275763759163 & 1.1084677419354834 & 0.9387096774193541 & 1.2782258064516134 & 1.144318181818182 & 1.0973591549295765 & 1.1823076923076916 & 0.7075471698113205 & 1.0629629629629622 & 1.1655913978494623 & 1.1280528052805279 & 0.7266666666666666 \\
 avril & 10.958888888888891 & 1.0731944444444466 & 1.062962962962963 & 1.3280961182994457 & 1.0864000000000005 \\ 
 mai & 13.655555555555546 & 0.7385416666666575 & ~ & 0.9904522613065327 & 0.9280898876404503 \\
\midrule
\RowStyle[bold]{\itshape}
Moyenne  &  9.96& 1.02 &1.2&1.3&0.97 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

Here is the result :

A nice option to NiceTabular or Siunitx would be to specify row number that we don’t want to be formatted.

A version using tabularray. It has the useful guard option that allows omitting braces for cells/rows/columns with S format but with non-number material. As you can see, the first row is formatted in math mode (so dollar signs are omitted as well), the font selection is also put into the table header.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{
detect-mode=,
output-decimal-marker = {.},
tight-spacing           = true,
group-digits            = false,
input-signs             = ,
round-mode              = places,
round-precision         = 2,
minimum-decimal-digits=2,
}

\begin{document}
\centering  
\begin{booktabs}{
  colspec={rSSSSS},
  row{1}={font=\boldmath,mode=math,guard},
  cell{1}{1}={font=\bfseries,mode=text},
  cell{6}{1}={font=\bfseries\itshape},
}
\toprule
 Mois & \overline{T^{\circ}C} & \Delta T & T<5^{\circ}C & 5\leq T^{\circ}C\leq 15 & T>15 \\
\midrule
 février & 8.47254464283035 & 1.4195684523541585 & 1.3283950620246907 & 1.569725557512863 & 1.1499999999999997 \\ 
 mars & 8.918010752688165 & 0.7305275763759163 & 1.1084677419354834 & 0.9387096774193541 & 1.2782258064516134 \\
 avril & 10.958888888888891 & 1.0731944444444466 & 1.062962962962963 & 1.3280961182994457 & 1.0864000000000005 \\ 
 mai & 13.655555555555546 & 0.7385416666666575 & -- & 0.9904522613065327 & 0.9280898876404503 \\
\midrule
 Moyenne & 9.96& 1.02 &1.2&1.3&0.97 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
\end{document}

The result:

